# VS code displays "Problems" when there are none

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I started  to use VS Code, and  I'm t   rying  to figure out an issue:

I've a very small basic code:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
window = QtGui.QWidget()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

First time I launched, I forgot the `[]` parameters in the `QApplication` constructor, so there was effectively an error. I now have corrected it, I can launch the app, the window is properly displayed, everything is fine.

BUT, VS Code continue to display me 2 errors:

```
{
    "resource": "/f:/Dev/python-ui/firstApp.py",
    "owner": "python",
    "code": "E1101",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "E1101:Module 'PySide.QtGui' has no 'QApplication' member",
    "source": "pylint",
    "startLineNumber": 4,
    "startColumn": 7,
    "endLineNumber": 4,
    "endColumn": 7
}
```

and

```
{
    "resource": "/f:/Dev/python-ui/firstApp.py",
    "owner": "python",
    "code": "E1101",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "E1101:Module 'PySide.QtGui' has no 'QWidget' member",
    "source": "pylint",
    "startLineNumber": 5,
    "startColumn": 10,
    "endLineNumber": 5,
    "endColumn": 10
}
```

What did I missed?

It's annoying because in the file list I then have the name in red.

Answer (score -1):

It means the linter you have chosen to run can't find those attributes on the object. Make sure that `PySide` is installed in the environment that you selected for VS Code and that the linter is able to find the package.

Comment: But since when I hit F5, the applications starts and I see PySide window, it means that PySide is correctly installed, right?

I didn't install myself any "linter", I guess it did came with the python package or with the VS Code directly

Comment: VS Code doesn't come with a linter, but it will prompt you to install PyLint. But if it's executing then it simply means PyLint isn't able to resolve the attribute.

Comment: Anyway, what should I do then?

Comment: Maybe file an issue with PyLint?

Comment: So, you think it's a big and not something I did wrong? I would find this very weird, no?

Comment: It's software too; bugs are always possible. ;) My key point is it is not an issue with VS Code, and so either PyLint is not installed and being run from the same environment that you have PySide installed into or PyLint simply can't deduce that there is an attribute as you expect.

Comment: Well, since I'm a total newbie in VS Code and python, I was suggesting that it highly possible that I made a mistake, and I would like to know how to check that everything is well configured.

Comment: Only other option is to run PyLint from the terminal to see if you get the same error. That will help diagnose if it has to do with the package not being installed in the expected location.